# How can n = c/v?

Tags: concentration

I know this question is probably really rudimentary or I may just be fundamentally misunderstanding something but I would really like to just understand this.

So $n=\pu{1 mole}$, $c=\pu{1 moles/L}$ and $v=\pu{1 L}$

This is how I learned this and it makes sense. However, this way, the equation doesn't make sense. It reads: $$\pu{moles}=\frac{\pu{moles/L}}{\pu{L}}$$

Which simplifies into $$\pu{moles}=\frac{\pu{moles}}{\pu{L}^2}$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D%28x%2Fl%29%2Fl

Which is obviously wrong. What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be $n=cv$

Then, your first equation

$$\pu{moles}=\frac{\pu{moles/L}}{\pu{L}}$$

becomes$$\pu{moles}=\pu{\frac{moles}{L}}\times\pu{L}=\pu{moles}$$

Comment: How are n, c and v then defined? Because if they are defined the way I defined them, then my equation still holds.

Comment: Or do you mean to say that the equation is n=cv not n=c/v?

Comment: yes this is correct. the equation is n=cv